# How to make 4 different calls to 4 different endpoints on same activity in android and pass the cumulative result to an adapter

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit2

I am developing an android app where i want to make 4 different api calls to different endpoints of the tmdbapi. I am using retrofit and java. How can i combine these calls within a single fragment wait for them to finish and pass all the results from each individual call to an adapter class for view binding.

Here is my retrofit tmdbapi client class.

```
package com.popularmovies.Model;




import retrofit2.Call;

import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface TMDBAPICLIENT {
    final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

    @GET("discover/movie")
    Call<DISCOVERPOJO> getDiscover(@Query("sort_by") String sort_by, @Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("trending/{media_type}/{time_window}")
    Call<TRENDINGPOJO> getTrending(@Path("media_type") String media_type, @Path("time_window") String time_window, @Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("person/popular")
    Call<DISCOVERPOJO> getPeople(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/top_rated")
    Call<DISCOVERPOJO> getTopRatedTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/popular")
    Call<DISCOVERPOJO> getPopularTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/on_the_air")
    Call<DISCOVERPOJO> getOnAirTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/airing_today")
    Call<DISCOVERPOJO> getAiringTodayTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

}
```

the calls I'm interested in in this context are the bottom 4.
I'm also a newbie at this. Sigh.

Comment: Why don't you use RxJava for this?

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi have any links to an handy tutorials??

Comment: Have a look at this. https://proandroiddev.com/rxjava-2-parallel-multiple-network-call-made-easy-1e1f14163eef

Answer (score 1):

You can use RXJava for this for sure.

do the following changes.

1) add dependencies, update them to latest if possible

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0')
        {
            exclude module: 'okhttp'
        }

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
```

2) In your retrofit networking call add a `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory`

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
  .build();
```

3) change your existing calls to something like below

```
public interface TMDBAPICLIENT {
    final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

    @GET("discover/movie")
    Observable<DISCOVERPOJO> getDiscover(@Query("sort_by") String sort_by, @Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("trending/{media_type}/{time_window}")
    Observable<TRENDINGPOJO> getTrending(@Path("media_type") String media_type, @Path("time_window") String time_window, @Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("person/popular")
    Observable<DISCOVERPOJO> getPeople(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/top_rated")
    Observable<DISCOVERPOJO> getTopRatedTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/popular")
    Observable<DISCOVERPOJO> getPopularTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/on_the_air")
    Observable<DISCOVERPOJO> getOnAirTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

    @GET("tv/airing_today")
    Observable<DISCOVERPOJO> getAiringTodayTv(@Query("api_key") String api_key);

}
```

4) Use merge zip operator to zip them together.

```
Observable.zip(getDiscover("desc","SECRET_KEY"), getPeople("asc","SECRET_KEY"), new Func2<DISCOVERPOJO, DISCOVERPOJO, ArrayList<TestData>>() {
            @Override
                public ArrayList<TestData> call(DISCOVERPOJO responseOne, DISCOVERPOJO responseTwo) {
                  ArrayList<TestData> testDataList = new ArrayList();
                      // process data from response responseOne & responseTwo
                  return testDataList;
            } 
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<TestData>>() {

        @Override
        public void onNext(ArrayList<TestData> testDataList) {
           //do something with new data
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted" ); 
            // you can show alert here or do something when completed 
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError Throwable: " + t.toString() );
        }
    });
```

where `ArrayList<TestData>` is the data we want to return from the zip operator. you can change this to something you want.